# Using VSCode text editor within webview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am interested in [creating a VSCode plugin](https://dev.to/reggi/proposing-a-new-way-to-write-javascript-7km) that would use a webview, but within the webview it would have a code-editor.

Is this possible? Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I found a similar question here with no answer:

[Custom VSCode extension: embed native editor in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754418/custom-vscode-extension-embed-native-editor-in-webview)

Comment: you might try https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/

Comment: This looks similar to a VSCode Notebook. Have you considered creating a custom NotebookProvider? https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/notebook